# Javascript Arrays printing undefined before the array items

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, initialization, undefined

I am having trouble printing a simple array list in javascript.
undefined is being printed before only two array items. please consider the code below;

```js
function buildList(){
    var box = document.getElementById("box");
 var startList  = "<ol>";
 var endList = "</ol>";
 var listItems;
      
        var arry = ["Go to shopping", "Go to Mall"];
   for(var i = 0; i < arry.length; i++){
            listItems += "<li>" + arry[i] + "</li>";
 }

 box.innerHTML = startList + listItems + endList;
}
document.onLoad(buildList());``
```

```html
<div id="box">
  
</div>
```

output of this is

undefined 
1) Go to shopping
2) Go to Mall

Please help.

Comment: You forgot to initialize `listItems`

Comment: Hi @knight, if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 6):

Your `listItem` variable is undefined because it is not initialized.

`var listItems = "" ;` (at line 5) should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring  `var listItems;` => undefined, you should do as follows: `var listItems = "";` => declared and initialized as an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize listItems.

var listItems = "";

What you are doing right now is adding a string to listItems, but you did not define listItems. It does not know what is listItem

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
In your code you missing `var listItems=""`;

Here is full code

```js
function buildList()
       {
    var box = document.getElementById("box");
    var startList  = "<ol>";
    var endList = "</ol>";
    var listItems="";

    var arry = ["Go to shopping", "Go to Mall"];

     for(var i = 0; i < arry.length; i++)
     {
  listItems += "<li>" + arry[i] + "</li>";
    }

   box.innerHTML = startList + listItems + endList;
      }

       document.onLoad(buildList());``
```

```html
<div id="box">
  
  </div>
```